# Converting rectangle bounding box from N, S, E, W decimal to a topmost NE, and bottom most SW rectangle

Tags: convert

I want to combine two different database applications with a search, and in order to do that I need convert a rectangle box from its N, S, E, W decimal coordinates to a a box that is amde up from a top NE and bottom SW point.

Any advice on what calculation would help me get started?

Comment: Welcome to GIS.SE. You could give a little bit more information on the DBs in question, the current structure of the data, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you just take the S and W for the SW corner and N and E for the NE corner? I might be missing something but I don't think there's any calculation necessary.

Comment: Well, I feel pretty silly right now.

Thanks for the response. I probably never would have realised this!